# Count the Number of Changes in a Date Column based on another Attribute

Tags: r, validation, data-mining

Hi everyone I have faced a problem during my data validation. I need to have the number of changes in a date column for every unique variable in name column. For example:

```
student.data <- data.frame(student_id = c (1:7),
                            student_name=c("Rick","Rick","Michelle","Michelle","Rick","Michelle","John"), 
                            mark = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25,459.4,846.65), 
                            date_of_exam = as.Date(c("2014-01-01","2013-09-23","2014-11-15","2014-05-11", "2014-01-01","2016-04-14","2015-05-12")))
```

I know for a fact that it is kind of complicated but the result must be:

```
>table

>"Rick"
1  
>"Michelle"
2  
>"John"
0
```

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.table` way :

```
library(data.table)

setDT(student.data)
student.data[, .(change = uniqueN(date_of_exam) - 1), student_name]

#   student_name change
#1:         Rick      1
#2:     Michelle      2
#3:         John      0
```

Or in base R :

```
aggregate(date_of_exam~student_name,student.data, function(x) length(unique(x)) - 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can group by student and count the number of distinct dates and subtract one:

```
library(dplyr)

student.data %>%
  group_by(student_name) %>%
  summarise(cnt = n_distinct(date_of_exam) -1)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  student_name   cnt
  <fct>        <dbl>
1 John             0
2 Michelle         2
3 Rick             1
```